# More aesthetically wrap text in a table?

Tags: tables, spacing, margins

I have a table that I must fit in one page but have difficulty doing so in any aesthetically pleasing manner. A MWE is pasted below.  Are there any suggestions to improve this?  Regretfully I haven't a clue where to begin.

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   DOCUMENT TYPE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[9pt]{article}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %Font
\usepackage{libertine}
%\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{slantsc}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm,textcomp,nicefrac} %Math

\usepackage{graphicx, subfigure} %graphics & nested graphics
\usepackage{float} %place graphics exactly where you desire with [H]
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{caption}

\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\definecolor{Blue}{rgb}{0,0.08,0.8}

\usepackage{tikz} %graphs
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, shapes, calc, positioning}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{hyperref} %References

\usepackage{lscape} %for landscape orientation

\usepackage{titletoc} %Table of contents 
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{} %Section format
\titleformat{\subsection}{\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{} %Subsection format
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\bfseries\em} %Subsubsection format
\renewcommand*\footnoterule{} %Remove footnote separator line
\usepackage[bottom=0.1in]{geometry} %Margins
\usepackage{setspace}%Spacing
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%Header and footer
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}
\rhead{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand*\footnoterule{} %Remove footnote separator line
\usepackage{booktabs}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Document
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{landscape}

{\bf \scshape Personal Record Table}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
      \begin{tabular}{|c|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|} \hline

         & {\bf Your Investment}
         & {\bf Total Investment}
         & {\bf Group 1 Invesment}
         & {\bf Group2 Investment}
         & {\bf Total payoffs from The Account}
         & {\bf Your payoffs from The Account}
         & {\bf Your private payoffs}
         & {\bf Your initial payoffs}
         & {\bf Cost of deduction points assigned}
         & {\bf Number of deduction points received}
         & {\bf Cost of deduction points received}
         & {\bf Losses from deductions}
         & {\bf Final payoffs for this period}
         & {\bf Total payoffs for all periods}\\

         \hline\hline

         {\bf 1} & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\[2ex]\hline
         {\bf 2} & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\[2ex]\hline
         {\bf 3} & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\[2ex]\hline
         {\bf 4} & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\[2ex]\hline
         {\bf 5} & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\[2ex]\hline
         {\bf 6} & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\[2ex]\hline
         {\bf 7} & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\[2ex]\hline
         {\bf 8} & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\[2ex]\hline
         {\bf 9} & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\[2ex]\hline
         {\bf 10} & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\[2ex]\hline

         \hline

      \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{landscape}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   END
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.sx. You can format code sections using the `{}` button in the editor (see my edit)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps something like this.  the headings still look poor, you could use a smaller font so they do not take so many lines, or perhaps?? you could re-word some to be shorter.

I added comments inline.

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   DOCUMENT TYPE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% article doesn't have a 9pt opttion, deleted.
\documentclass{article}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %Font
\usepackage{libertine}
%\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{slantsc}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm,textcomp,nicefrac} %Math

\usepackage{graphicx, subfigure} %graphics & nested graphics
\usepackage{float} %place graphics exactly where you desire with [H]
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{caption}

\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\definecolor{Blue}{rgb}{0,0.08,0.8}


% not for MWE, speeds thing sup:-)
%\usepackage{tikz} %graphs
%\usetikzlibrary{arrows, shapes, calc, positioning}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{hyperref} %References

\usepackage{lscape} %for landscape orientation

\usepackage{titletoc} %Table of contents 
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{} %Section format
\titleformat{\subsection}{\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{} %Subsection format
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\bfseries\em} %Subsubsection format
\renewcommand*\footnoterule{} %Remove footnote separator line
\usepackage[bottom=0.1in]{geometry} %Margins
\usepackage{setspace}%Spacing
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%Header and footer
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}
\rhead{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand*\footnoterule{} %Remove footnote separator line
\usepackage{booktabs}




%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Document
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{landscape}


%\bf obsolete in latex2e, and anyway looks like a heading to me.
\section*{Personal Record Table}


%\begin{table}[H] % table not needed here (and H not defined unless you load float package)
\centering
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}% keep letters off the lines.

% using r not c for numeric column,
% make p columns narrower, so they fit on page
      \begin{tabular}{|>{\bfseries}r|*{14}{>{\bfseries\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.2cm}|}}
\hline

         & Your Investment
         & Total Investment
         & Group 1 Invesment
         & Group2 Investment
         & Total payoffs from The Account
         & Your payoffs from The Account
         & Your private payoffs
         & Your initial payoffs
         & Cost of deduction points assigned
         & Number of deduction points received
         & Cost of deduction points received
         & Losses from deductions
         & Final payoffs for this period
         & Total payoffs for all periods\\




         \hline\hline

         1 & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\[2ex]\hline
         2 & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\[2ex]\hline
         3 & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\[2ex]\hline
         4 & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\[2ex]\hline
         5 & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\[2ex]\hline
         6 & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\[2ex]\hline
         7 & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\[2ex]\hline
         8 & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\[2ex]\hline
         9 & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\[2ex]\hline
         10 & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\[2ex]\hline
      \end{tabular}


\end{landscape}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   END
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

I have some suggestions:

- Use the `rotating` package and its `sidewaystable` environment to place a table in landscape mode.
- Use something like `\usepackage[vmargin=0.5in]{geometry}` to provide maximum space for the table.
- Use the `tabularx` package and its eponymous environment, with a width of `\textwidth`; let the package compute the widths of the 14 [!] data columns automatically. Since the `tabularx` environment is set to occupy `\textwidth`, there's no need (or point) in `\centering` the table.
- Use `\raggedright` instead of the default full justification for the data columns.
- It's not clear to me what the role of the string `Personal Record Table` is. I'm assuming it belongs in a `\caption` command; however, I may be wrong.
- Issue the instruction `\small` *inside* the `sidewaystable` environment to reduce the fontsize by 10%, and reduce the amount of intercolumn whitespace by setting `\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}`. (The default value of this parameter is `6pt`.) These two changes succeed in reducing the number of rows needed for the headers to 4.

Further remarks:

- The option `9pt` isn't recognized and thus ignored by the `article` document class. I've therefore deleted it from the code below. The `article` document class recognizes only `10pt` (default), `11pt`, and `12pt` as fontsize-related options.
- The macro `{\bf ...}` is PlainTeX; for LaTeX documents it's much better to use `\textbf{...}`.
- Your example code contains a lot of material that's not relevant for the table at hand; I've taken the liberty of stripping the code down to what's essential for typesetting the table.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[vmargin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{rotating} % for sidewaystable environment
\usepackage{tabularx} % for tabularx environment
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\small % 10% reduction of fontsize, i.e., from 10pt to 9pt
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt} % default value: 6pt
\caption{Personal Record Table}

\medskip

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|*{14}{Y|}}
\hline
& \textbf{Your Investment}
& \textbf{Total Investment}
& \textbf{Group1 Investment}
& \textbf{Group2 Investment}
& \textbf{Total payoffs from The Account}
& \textbf{Your payoffs from The Account}
& \textbf{Your private payoffs}
& \textbf{Your initial payoffs}
& \textbf{Cost of deduction points assigned}
& \textbf{Number of deduction points received}
& \textbf{Cost of deduction points received}
& \textbf{Losses from deductions}
& \textbf{Final payoffs for this period}
& \textbf{Total payoffs for all periods}\\
\hline\hline
\textbf{1} & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\[2ex]\hline
\textbf{2} & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\[2ex]\hline
\textbf{3} & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\[2ex]\hline
\textbf{4} & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\[2ex]\hline
\textbf{5} & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\[2ex]\hline
\textbf{6} & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\[2ex]\hline
\textbf{7} & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\[2ex]\hline
\textbf{8} & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\[2ex]\hline
\textbf{9} & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\[2ex]\hline
\textbf{10} & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\[2ex]\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the baselines in the headers look larger than necessary.  (take a look at the spacing between the lines "payoff" and "from".)  also, a slightly smaller size wouldn't be detrimental, and might avoid a few hyphenated words.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Thanks. Will post a reworked example with (i) a `\small` directive in effect for the table (so that the font size will be 9pt rather than 10pt) and (ii) a lower value for `\tabcolsep` (so that more material will fit on each line). The baseline distances in the headers are, in fact, perfectly constant; it's just that one gap looks wider than the other because it happens to feature (virtually) no characters with descenders & ascenders whereas the next gap happens to have lots of them.